# Some CSS elements are not showing

Tags: html, css

Building a new website and using the 960 grid system, with the following css:
960_24_col
text
rest

I'm also using my own style.css.

So, I am trying to apply the following css to my header 2 (h2)

```
h2 {
font-size: 26px;
text-transform: lowercase;
border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to apply. When I inspect the element in Chrome, some of the h2 elements are crossed out (line through it) in my style.css...when I copy the above code to say text.css..its works (but also applies to the other h1, h2, h3 etc)

Any of you css wizards go any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the order in which the css rules are included inside your html markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS files are read in order. So if one file is loaded which sets style on `h1`, and another file is loaded that also sets style on `h1`, the second one will overrule the first.

A nasty way to fix that is to add `!important` to the end of your style, ie:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow !important;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using !important, re-order the rules.

Comment: Totally agree, `!important` but reading the questions iI get the feeling that reordering might not be an option. `!important` will definatly fix his issues. .. Once again i do agree that reordering is preferred.

Comment: Nice one guys, the "!important;" worked...but I see what you mean about re-ordering...that might be better practice? When you say reorder, do you mean which css file is loaded first, or which css element is loaded first? Thanks again guys

Comment: Exactly. Take the knowledge of the fact that css statements override eachother and make that work to your advantage. So basicall: load a basic css first, then add a more precise css etc. (ie. set default font on h1 and override only when neccesary). usually this saves alot of unneccesary CSS.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense...I linked to the 960 css files first, then called my style.css last...boom. You guys are awesome...thanks for the clear and precise answers. I even learned something new (load basic css first, then add a more precise css afterwards)

Comment: I need more "reputation"...cant up vote you (just so you know)

Comment: That is no problem. Accepting the answer is enough for the archives. Good ot see your problem is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

There must be some other style also defined for h2 in style.css the *strike-through* in chrome inspector means that this style has been over ridden, try finding any other occurrences for `h2` in `style.css`

Or if you want to keep both of style definitions due to some intentional changes you made try using `!important` after respective property which you don’t want to be over-ridden to ask browser to give top priority to this style instead of others

```
h2 {
font-size: 26px !important; /*same with every other property you want to give top priority*/
text-transform: lowercase;
border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There are some h2 styling in the text.css which comes with the 960 grid. How can I make the h2 in my styles.css take control over the text.css?

Comment: Use `!important` as I mentioned above it'll override any other styles present elsewhere and your this style will be applied with first priority to the elements.

Comment: Thanks Sajjad, at least I know if im desperate I can use the "!important"...which will then help me troubleshoot my issue. Cheers man